# Volatile reads/writes and instruction reordering

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile, memory-barriers

There is a very good article by Joe Albahari explaining `volatile` in C#: [Threading in C#: PART 4: ADVANCED THREADING](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx).

Considering instruction reordering Joe uses this example:

```cs
public class IfYouThinkYouUnderstandVolatile
{
  private volatile int x, y;

  private void Test1() // Executed on one thread
  {
    this.x = 1; // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int a = this.y; // Volatile read (acquire-fence)
  }

  private void Test2() // Executed on another thread
  {
    this.y = 1; // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int b = this.x; // Volatile read (acquire-fence)
  }
}
```

Basically what he is saying is that `a` and `b` both could end up with containing `0` when the methods are running on different threads in parallel.

IOW the optimizer or processor could reorder the instructions as follows:

```cs
public class IfYouThinkYouUnderstandVolatileReordered
{
  private volatile int x, y;

  private void Test1() // Executed on one thread
  {
    int tempY = this.y; // Volatile read (reordered)
    this.x = 1; // Volatile write
    int a = tempY; // Use the already read value
  }

  private void Test2() // Executed on another thread
  {
    int tempX = this.x; // Volatile read (reordered)
    this.y = 1; // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int b = tempX; // Use the already read value
  }
}
```

The reason why this can happen though we are using `volatile` is that a **read instruction** following a **write instruction** can be moved before the **write instruction**.

So far I understand what is happening here.

My question is: *could this reordering work through stack frames?* I mean can a volatile write instruction be moved after a volatile read instruction which is happening in another method (or property accessor)?

Have a look at the following code: it is working with properties instead of directly accessing instance variables.

What about reordering in this case? Could it happen in any case? Or could it only happen if the property access is inlined by the compiler?

```cs
public class IfYouThinkYouUnderstandVolatileWithProps
{
  private volatile int x, y;

  public int PropX
  {
    get { return this.x; }
    set { this.x = value; }
  }

  public int PropY
  {
    get { return this.y; }
    set { this.y = value; }
  }

  private void Test1() // Executed on one thread
  {
    this.PropX = 1; // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int a = this.PropY; // Volatile read (acquire-fence)
  }

  private void Test2() // Executed on another thread
  {
    this.PropY = 1; // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int b = this.PropX; // Volatile read (acquire-fence)
  }
}
```

Comment: `volatile` doesn't stop **all** the reordering. With this keyword same type operations still can be reordered (like two reads before writing and two writes before reading).

Answer (score 1):

You should not think about such high levels things because you can't control them.
JIT has many reasons to inline or not.
Reordering is a good concept which allows you to reason about possible outcomes of parallel code execution. But the real things happening are not only about reordering read/write operations. It can be real reordering or caching values in  CPU registers by JIT, or effects of speculative execution by the CPU itself, or  how memory controller does its job.

Think of  reads and writes of pieces of memory of pointer (or less) size. Use reordering **model** of such reads and writes and don't rely on  today's specifics of the JIT or CPU your program runs on.

Answer (score 1):

As said in ECMA-335

> I.12.6.4 Optimization 
>   Conforming implementations of the CLI are **free to execute** programs **using any technology that guarantees, within a single thread of execution, that side-effects and exceptions generated by a thread are visible in the order specified by the CIL.**  For this purpose only volatile operations (including volatile reads) constitute visible side-effects.  (Note that while only volatile operations constitute visible side-effects, volatile operations also affect the visibility of non-volatile references.)
>    Volatile operations are specified in §I.12.6.7. There are no ordering guarantees relative to exceptions injected into a thread by another thread (such exceptions are sometimes called “asynchronous exceptions” 
>   (e.g., System.Threading.ThreadAbortException).

So, obviously it's allowed to inline all that code and then it's the same as it was.